# HTML CSS: How to copy and paste div block elements into Notepad while retaining the white space?

Tags: css, html, whitespace, block

I'm trying to make a chord website where you can take lyrics and put chords above them.

While I was able to position the chords successfully above the lyrics by spanning them separately, displaying them in a block, and then wrapping them in another span which displays inline-block, when I try to copy and paste them into Notepad, it doesn't retain the whitespace and instead pastes them as separate elements.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/CPYTg/3/

The setup:

```
 <li class="pair" onclick="javascript:doNote(0);"> 
            <span class="chord" id="ch_0">E</span><span class="lyric" id="ly_0">Tonight</span>
        </li>
li.pair {display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;}
.lyric {display:block;}
.chord {display:block;text-align:center;}
```

As you can see, the chords and lyrics display correctly in the browser, but when it comes to copying and pasting them into Notepad, it formats them as separate items. Is there any way to remedy this so that when you copy and paste them, it retains the whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you should be able to use 'pre' tags which mean pre-formatted. So the stuff inside the tags isn't really 'parsed' by the browser as HTML, the browser just spits out the characters on the screen as it finds them in the HTML file. Try this, (with no indenting in the HTML):

```
<preX>
   E                   G#m            C#m
Tonight I'm gonna have myself a real good time
        F#m   B         E    
I feel alive and the world...
</preX>
```

Obviously remove the X from the tags, this is just so stackoverflow won't parse it. This will show in the browser how it looks and will copy/paste fine to notepad.

Comment: The thing is, what I am trying to do is parse the lyrics and make it easy to insert a chord above them, and that means simply changing the HTML of the <span> element to whatever the user inputs. Having to use pre in the HTML to format everything is a completely different method to go about what I'm trying to do. But if it's the only way to get the characters to show up in notepad the way they are supposed to be, I guess having to use pre is my only option.

Comment: OK, you could have each row of text its own 'pre' with an onclick event. On click, use javascript to get the position of the click (e.g. clicking on 'tonight' might be 4 characters in). And insert the chord at the correct position (above the 'i' in tonight). See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrt42/

Comment: That is a good solution, but then you're limited to pre formatting only. In my example, I was able to change the font of the lyrics and chords as well, since they are being thought of as pairs of divs that are displayed together and so will always be formatted correctly independent of the font. Although I could use your method if trying to copy to plaintext.

Comment: Yeah, your other option is to have an 'export' function which goes through the data and inserts the correct number of spaces. You'll always run into problems if the user doesn't have mono-spaced fonts though.

Comment: That's what I figured. Probably use the javascript element.oncopy() function to parse the chords to plain text. This was my idea for the logic of doing so:

    var spacing=0;
    for each word in a line{
    if(word.chord) exists{
         place chord in position(spacing)
}
 spacing+=currentword.length;
}